# ActivityAlias label not taken from resource

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-activity-alias

I have two launcher in my app, one is a normal `activity` with the intent-filter for launcher/main and the other one is an `activityAlias`.

For both, I supply labels in the `manifest` via my `strings.xml` resources.
The reason for this is, that I want to provide different labels in different 
locales.

Unfortunately only the label of my `activity` is changed accordingly to the 
language selected in the android settings.

Why is that?

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

and the alias

```
<activity-alias android:name=".MainAlias" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:exported="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/alias_icon" 
    android:label="@string/alias_label" 
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">                                             
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>   
        </intent-filter> 
</activity-alias>
```

Comment: How did you test this? If you tested it by installing your app and then changing the locale, the home screen launcher of your device or emulator may be improperly caching some information. In that case, reboot. Or, uninstall and reinstall the app and see if the proper translation shows up.

Comment: I changed my locale in the android settings and reinstalled my application. I expected the labels to be different after the installation, but only the activity did.

Comment: Do you have alias_label in both `strings.xml` files in their respectful `values` folders?

Comment: Yep, the resource name is also equal in both xml files.